# I need to combine multiple lines starting with the same ID

Tags: regex, database, csv, parsing

I have multiple lines in a text file that I need to combine together. The file is about 200 million lines long, so opening it with Excel and using their built-in tools is out of the picture.

The first set of lines looks like this:

```
1,example@gmail.com,Username
3,example@gmail.com,Username
4,example@gmail.com,Username
5,example@gmail.com,Username
9,example@gmail.com,Username
10,example@gmail.com,Username
```

Second set which I want to add at the last line of the first set is:

```
1,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
3,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
4,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
5,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
9,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
10,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
```

If anyone has experience with this, I'd love some help

Comment: Looking at the data, what's the intent of this program? Looks to me like you have a CSV of emails, username, and a hashed password. Who on earth would ever need to do this in a normal environment? Something looks fishy  to me.

Comment: I need to restore a database backup for a client, and it was backed up in a really weird way. One way I could do this is by making a regex to identify bcrypt hashes, add commas in front and using sql to combine lines with the same ID, but this would be really inefficient, so I'm asking here

Comment: This client of yours has 200 million users?

Comment: They do security evals for a number of big clients, but its mostly duplicates which is a whole other issue I'll have to deal with later

Comment: You understand my hesitation with this... Are both sets of CSV data in the same file?

Comment: Yeah I mean I need to respect their privacy, so I can't really go into too much detail without giving away who its for, but It's all in a single file yeah.

Comment: `^(\d+),(.*$)(?=[\s\S]*^\1,(.*))`, then use `$1,$2,$3` to put the data back together.

Comment: Seems to work fine, appreciate the help. Wanna make this a full answer in case someone has a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

Regex

```
^(\d+),(.*$)(?=[\s\S]*^\1,(.*))
```

Formatting output

```
$1,$2,$3
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
1,example@gmail.com,Username
3,example@gmail.com,Username
4,example@gmail.com,Username
5,example@gmail.com,Username
9,example@gmail.com,Username
10,example@gmail.com,Username
1,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
3,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
4,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
5,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
9,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
10,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
```

#### Output

```
1,example@gmail.com,Username,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
3,example@gmail.com,Username,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
4,example@gmail.com,Username,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
5,example@gmail.com,Username,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
9,example@gmail.com,Username,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
10,example@gmail.com,Username,$2a$10$gdsZkf62vUfwHQX8pUGe2.7zqvBvcIPWseaJmboJw3U2sxDj18y5q
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of a line
- `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 1
- `,` Match the comma character `,` literally
- `(.*$)` Capture any number of any character (except newline characters) until the asserted position at the end of the line (asserting end of line position dramatically reduces steps) into capture group 2
- `(?=[\s\S]*^\1,(.*))` Positive lookahead asserting what follows matches

  - `[\s\S]*` Match any number of any character (`\s`: any whitespace character; `\S`: any non-whitespace character)
  - `^` Assert position at the start of a line
  - `\1` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
  - `,` Matches the comma character `,` literally
  - `(.*)` Capture any number of any character into capture group 3